# Intel Galileo sd card interface

Tags: intel, intel-galileo

now we are currently working on intel galileo arduino compatible board. In that we are interfacing 3 sensors to the galileo board. We want to store those sensor's data into sd card. So, the question is, how can we access the sdcard and write those data into sd card. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried working with the micro SD card slot on the Intel Galileo? You can run a Linux image from there and also save all sensor relevant data.

Comment: SD library itself is working. I updated the firmware and now we don't need to use any SD breakout board. Thanks for the replies and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Arduino SD library to read/write to the SD card. There is a bug, however, that if the file was not already there on the SD card, it must be created first using a Linux command. Please see https://communities.intel.com/thread/46635 for a workaround.

Comment: we are plan to use sd card breakout board. So, should i use sd library or spi based code. Please can you suggest?